# qpdfview 0.4.14, "could not load plug-in for file type 'PDF'!"

Tags: pdf

I upgraded to `qpdfview` 0.4.14 today on Ubuntu 15.04. After doing it, PDF files were failed to open with the following msg:

> could not load plug-in for file type 'PDF'!
>   could not open <~file path>

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the reason why it was failed.

`libpoppler-qt5.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So just downloading relevant package from `Synaptic Package Manager` solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't understand what you have said here. What I did was remove already installed Qpdfview package and then reinstalled from synaptic. but problem continuoued

Comment: The problem is that the qpdfview version 4.14 which comes from an external source and not the offical repos unless you are running the development release,  does not pull in a dependency of the libpopler-qt5-1 package which provides the needed library for qpdfview to open pdf files. Try searching for libpoppler-qt5-1 and installing that in synaptic.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpoppler-qt5-1