# Software launch from terminal always points to the old version

Tags: software-center

I installed a software from its source in the previous version, which was saved in `/usr/local` folder. Now I want to update to the latest version with provided DEB package. After installing it, the launch from terminal points the software to the old location `/usr/local`, rather than to the new version.

During the installation, a message appeared that "An old version is available in your normal software channels. Only install this file if you trust the origin." And there is no old version let me delete in the software center.

How can I delete the old version and update to the new version under such circumstances?

Comment: Which software do you mean? First you have to remove the installation in `/usr/local`. Per default, this folder has a higher priority in you PATH definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers because these are two different problems:

1. First you have to remove the installation in `/usr/local`. Per default this folder has a higher priority in the PATH definition. I guess you are talking about [qpdfview](https://askubuntu.com/q/629814/367165).

   - If you still have the source folder of the application execute

     ```
     sudo make uninstall
     ```

     in this folder.
   - If not ... remove the files

     ```
     sudo rm /usr/local/bin/qpdfview
     sudo rm /usr/local/lib/mime/packages/qpdfview
     sudo rm /usr/local/lib/qpdfview/libqpdfview_pdf.so
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/applications/qpdfview.desktop
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/doc/qpdfview/changelog.Debian.gz
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/doc/qpdfview/copyright
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/qpdfview.svg
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/qpdfview.1.gz
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/menu/qpdfview
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/qpdfview/help.html
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/qpdfview/qpdfview.xpm
     ```

     and next time use `sudo checkinstall` to create and install a DEB package instead of `sudo make install` **;)**
2. The message

   > An old version is available in your normal software channels. Only install this file if you trust the origin.

   appears when you added a PPA and the standard Ubuntu repositories also provides a version for this package.